# How to generate Angular2 app inside cordova pp

Tags: angular, cordova

I have been looking for resources that explains how to use Angular 2 inside a Cordova app and it seems like there aren't any that explain in simple terms how to do this.  For instance, after generating a cordova app with: `cordova create sampleApp`, do I cd into the www folder and then run ng2 cli command: `ng new angularSideApp`?  Question is:

1) where do I run the ng command?
2) after I run this command, what changes do I need to make in my cordova files so that the code I write in Angular can be compiled and work with cordova.

In other words, how do I set up an Angular 2 app to work in Cordova, or if I already have a Cordova app set up, how do I add Angular 2 to it and make it all work?

Comment: This should help. https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2

Answer (score 1):

### Step1

First you need to Create Your Angular2 Project.

### Step2

After that inside angular2 project you need to create cordova project.

cordova create MyApp

### Step 3

After that goto your cordova project directory

cd MyApp             //change your Project Directory cordova

cordova platform add browser    //add browser platform to your cordova app

cordova run browser           //run your cordova project

rm -r www                    //Remove the www directory because you can add your angular2 project build files here.

### Step 4

Change your Angular2 Project directory and build following command

ng build --target=production --environment=prod --output-path MyApp/www/

//(MyApp/www) is your Cordova project path

### Step 5

Change your Cordova Project

cd MyApp

Run Your Cordova app

cordova run browser

You will see Your Angular 2 application run in inside the cordova app.
@charlitos if u have any clarify 
visit this site 
https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2